# Efficient method for finding Sudoku Hidden Singles in Python

Tags: python, list, sudoku

I am writing a sudoku solver with human-like tactics. I wrote a couple of methods for finding **hidden singles on a box**, that is, to check if there is only one cell available for a given candidate to be placed within the box ("hidden" means even if the cell itself has more candidates).

I use the following structure for the lists: the `board[9][9]` stores the placed numbers from 1 to 9, and 0 if there is no placed number. the `possibles[9][9][9]` stores the candidates for a given cell, and 0 if the candidate is already eliminated. Since I am also writing the GUI with Pygame, I prefer not to remove elements from the `possibles`, thus, if the cell has only the number 5 as candidate, the possible list would be `possibles[i][j] = [0, 0, 0, 0, 5, 0, 0, 0, 0]`.

Here's the hidden single method:

```
def hidden_singles(board, possibles):
    # CHECK BOX
    print("method 1")
    hiddenSinglesPos_box = []
    t0 = time.time()
    iterations = 0
    # iterate over each cell in the board
    for i, row in enumerate(board):
        for j, bnum in enumerate(row):
            # if the cell already has a placed number, skip
            if bnum != 0:
                continue

            # get box index
            ii = 3 * (i // 3)
            jj = 3 * (j // 3)

            # reduce the candidate list of cell to only non-zeros
            p = [_ for _ in possibles[i][j] if _ != 0]

            # for each candidate, check the box for a hidden single !?!?
            for k, pnum in enumerate(p):
                count = 0
                for ibox in range(ii, ii + 3):
                    for jbox in range(jj, jj + 3):
                        # skip again if the cell within the box has a placed number
                        if board[ibox][jbox] != 0:
                            continue
                        iterations += 1
                        if possibles[ibox][jbox][pnum - 1] != 0:
                            count += 1
                if count == 1:
                    hiddenSinglesPos_box.append([i, j, pnum])
    deltaT = time.time() - t0
    print(deltaT)
    print(f"Iterations: {iterations}")
    print(f"{len(hiddenSinglesPos_box)} hidden singles")
    print(hiddenSinglesPos_box)
```

It is worth mentioning that, before calling this method, I have already eliminated the obvious non-candidates by checking row, col and box.

This works and it finds the hidden singles with ~1000 iterations, but surely it can be improved. I noticed that I could remove a candidate from the box search as soon as the second match is found. For instance, if the first cell in the box has the candidates [1, 2, 3] and the second cell has [1, 2, 4], there is no need to check candidates 1 and 2 for the second cell (I do not know how to do that without overcomplicating everything though). I do visit every board cell because that is the way I found to keep track not only of the existence of hidden single in a box but also its coordinate.

I am a beginner in Python and in coding too, so I am accepting suggestions about this method or about the structure in general and how I store the board, possibles, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have an interesting problem. To get "less" iterations, use abstraction like sets. This makes interpreter call compiled routines (mostly written in c) instead of parsing complex python logic.

```py
board = [
    [0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 7, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 8, 6, 5, 4, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
]

fullSet = list(range(1, len(board)+1))
zero = set([0])

def findPossibles(board):
    result = [None] * len(board)
    for y in range(len(board)):
        result[y] = [None] * len(board[0])
        for x in range(len(board[0])):
            result[y][x] = fullSet.copy()

    for y, row in enumerate(result):
        for x, e in enumerate(row):
            if board[y][x] != 0:
                e = [0] * 9
            for i in range(len(board)):
                num = board[i][x]
                if num != 0: e[num-1] = 0
            for i in range(len(board[0])):
                num = board[y][i]
                if num != 0: e[num-1] = 0
    return result

def findSingles(board, possibles):
    result = []

    for y in range(3):
        for x in range(3):
            taken = set()
            # collect quadrant values
            for iy in range(y*3, y*3+3):
                for ix in range(x*3, x*3+3):
                    taken.add(board[iy][ix])

            # find hidden singles
            for iy in range(y*3, y*3+3):
                for ix in range(x*3, x*3+3):
                    res = set(possibles[iy][ix]) - taken - zero
                    if len(res) == 1:
                        result.append((ix, iy, list(res)[0]))
    return result

import time

t0 = time.time()
possibles = findPossibles(board)
singles = findSingles(board, possibles)
print(time.time() - t0)
print(singles) # [(1, 7, 9)]
```

The code handling hidden singles should make around 162 iterations.

## Edit

I came up with this algorithm, using dictionary to collect all possible positions for a number inside a quadrant. Then the ones that have only one possible position are collected. I also improved outer complexity of `findPossibles` and replaces lists with sets. We can discus code further in comments.

```
board = [
    [9, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 9, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 7, 9, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 8, 6, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 9, 0, 0]
]

fullSet = set(range(1, len(board)+1))

def findPossibles(board):
    sz = len(board)
    br = range(sz)
    result = [None] * sz
    for y in br:
        result[y] = [None] * sz
        for x in br:
            result[y][x] = fullSet.copy()

    for y, row in enumerate(board):
        taken = set(row)
        for x in br:
            result[y][x] -= taken

    for x in br:
        taken = set()
        for y in br:
            taken.add(board[y][x])
        for y in br:
            result[y][x] -= taken
    
    for y in range(3):
        for x in range(3):
            taken = set()
            rx = x * 3
            ry = y * 3
            
            for iy in range(ry, ry+3):
                for ix in range(rx, rx+3):
                    taken.add(board[iy][ix])

            for iy in range(ry, ry+3):
                for ix in range(rx, rx+3):
                    result[iy][ix] -= taken

    return result

def findSingles(possibles):
    result = []
    for y in range(3):
        for x in range(3):
            table = {i:[] for i in fullSet}
            rx = x * 3
            ry = y * 3

            for iy in range(ry, ry+3):
                for ix in range(rx, rx+3):
                    for p in possibles[iy][ix]:
                        table[p].append((ix, iy))

            for p in table:
                if len(table[p]) == 1:
                    result.append(table[p][0] + (p,))

    return result

import time

t0 = time.time()
possibles = findPossibles(board)
singles = findSingles(possibles)
print(time.time() - t0)
print(singles) # [(1, 7, 9)]
```

## Edit 2

To improve the method `findPossibles`, we should assign an empty set for the candidates in cells with already placed numbers.

```py
def findPossibles(board):
    sz = len(board)
    br = range(sz)
    result = [None] * sz
    for y in br:
        result[y] = [None] * sz
        for x in be:
            # check if this board cell is empty
            if board[y][x] == 0:
                result[y][x] = fullSet.copy()
            else:
                result[y][x] = set()
```

Comment: the cell [1,7] is a naked single, not hidden. You can still put the 9 elsewhere in the box. I
tweaked your example to make that cell a hidden single for the 9. board = [[9, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],[0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],[0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],[0, 0, 9, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],[0, 0, 7, 9, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],[0, 0, 8, 6, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 9, 0, 0]] . For this board, your method does not find the hidden single. You showed me some interesting tricks that I am still studying. Looking forward to your reply.

Comment: yea, problem is that I am not really into sudoku and this terminology is unknown for me. Nevertheless, I can try to do this once again now that I know what hidden single is. (example of board with hidden single is better then explanation)

Comment: Sorry for the delay, I needed some time to study sets and tables. Your code had a small flaw in the _findPossibles()_ method: you should do this 'result[y][x] = fullSet.copy()' only in the cells where the board is 0, and when it's not, should be empty 'result[y][x] = set()'. With this, your code passed all my test boards. Using dicts to store the possible cell for the candidates was quite clever. I am actually re-writing my code to make use of sets and dicts now.

Comment: Nice, you can make an edit to fix that bug in my code. Its really pleasure to help someone who actually reads the code, I write, and tries to understand it. Sometimes people just say its not working and that's it.